# Does ECS with Fargate support Detailed Monitoring? If so, how do I enable it for a service in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I'd like to enable 1-minute resolution of the CloudWatch metrics `ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization` and `ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization`. I understand that by default, they are only updated every 5 minutes unless you enabled Detailed Monitoring, but I'm unclear on how to enable this.

I googled around and had no luck, only finding descriptions of what Detailed Monitoring is, how much it costs, etc.

I looked through both these documents:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service

but see no mention of it.

Is this maybe an account setting instead of an IaaC setting?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you are looking for is [ECS Container Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-container-insights.html).

You enable that at the ECS cluster level in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "my-cluster"

  setting {
    name  = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }
}
```